# What to do if I review something in multiple queues?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

How do I handle a bad post I see in multiple review queues, for example Triage and First Posts.  In this particular case I first saw it in the First Post queue - I flagged it for closure and downvoted.  Then I saw in in the Triage queue, and I'm uncertain of what I should have done (I just skipped it).  Is there a generally accepted method of handling this?

Comment: I'm really curious how so many people are running into this all of a sudden... Used to think of this as mostly a problem on sites that only had like 2 reviewers.

Comment: I don't know about generally accepted, but I skip such posts, except on the rare occasions I made a mistake the first time.

Comment: @Shog9 It feels that this occures atleast once a day, although most likely it will only be every third day.

Comment: Related: [Which action should I take if I already flagged to close outside the VLQ queue?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244829/259693) on MSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this happen to me quite a few times, especially now that different queues are feeding into each other.

I don't see any reason to not flag or vote based on the quality, regardless of whether or not you've seen/taken action on the post before.

The system already will not allow you to flag the post more than once if you've already seen it somewhere else and voted to close/flagged (if you try to flag in this case, most of the options except "Other" will be greyed out).

I would say that you should go ahead and take action based on the quality of the post. If you saw the post in Triage and it wasn't very good, so you put "Should be improved," then you see it down the road in Very Low Quality and the post fits the criteria for being deleted, vote to close/delete. No reason to skip it just because you've seen it before.

Comment: And if the best action (like flagging) isn't available, is skipping then preferred?

Comment: I agree that I should take whatever action is appropriate when I can, however (in theory at least) the appropriate action won't be available to me in the second queue - I would have already flagged/voted to close/delete, or made the necessary edit to the post.  This seems to force me to skip, which isn't a terrible choice, but I was hoping there was an alternative option

Comment: If the best actions aren't available, you have no option but to skip. There isn't an alternative action, because voting to close/flagging more than once aren't really options.